# Table exists error running schema:update console command

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine

Running `doctrine:schema:update --dump-sql` to establish a one-to-one relationship from an existing Household entity to a new Seeking entity results in the error

> The table with name 'projectmana.household' already exists.

Dev mode debug toolbar shows Invalid entities 0. What is the source of the error?

Household entity includes:

```
/**
 *
 * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="Seeking")
 */
protected $seeking;

public function getSeeking()
{
    return $this->seeking;
}
```

Seeking entity includes:

```
/**
 * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
 */
protected $id;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(name="seeking", type="string", nullable=false)
 * @Assert\NotBlank(message="Service may not be blank")
 */
protected $seeking;

public function setSeeking($seeking)
{
    $this->seeking = $seeking;
    return $this;
}

public function getSeeking()
{
    return $this->seeking;
}
```

Comment: You should provide the headers of this entity classes, how your entity annotations looks like?

Comment: Well, doh! This is what I get for not paying attention when copying!. The Seeking entity header had `@ORM\Table(name="household")`.  Post an answer and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the annotation of your new class.